# Django + Apache, browser always loading and none data received

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, no-response

I am running Django site in Apache with mod_wsgi.

The site **works before**. Today when I am try to install a [tokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) on the same server, I found the site become failed that when I open the django site, the chrome always loading and after a long long time it say "no data received".

The django site works on my development machine and another virtual machine.

On the amazon ec2:

- When I use wget on static files (.css, .img) served by apache, it received normally.
- But when I use wget on dynamic page from django, it stoped at *awaiting response...* , which means the problem is on the django + apache part.

I check the apache log that each time I refresh the browser, it will loading the django setting again, but nothing else. The log shows it did not enter the view function (I am not sure whether it entered the url routine or not):

```
[Sat Nov 19 02:15:54 2011] [error] Absolute_dir: /home/www/jdlab-browser/trunk/jdlab_browser
[Sat Nov 19 02:15:54 2011] [error] Using Amazon Server Settings
[Sat Nov 19 02:15:54 2011] [error] Absolute_dir: /home/www/jdlab-browser/trunk/jdlab_browser
[Sat Nov 19 02:15:54 2011] [error] Using Amazon Server Settings
```

I tried to uninstall tokuwiki, reinstall apache, mod_wsgi, django. Rewrite the apache configure file.

### Other information:

I opened the Debug mode of Django, and when I visit a not exist page, Django's **page not found error** page showed on the browser.

When I open the django's admin console **mysitename/admin/** , browser also did not received any data.

Any clu where to check next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found the problem is caused by **scipy** package.

And then I found a similar problem asked by other people.
[using-scipy-stats-stats-in-django-after-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819588/using-scipy-stats-stats-in-django-after-deployment)

Comment: i know its been a really long time, but could you please tell me how you isolated the cause to scipy?

Comment: @n3rV3 My method may not fit your case. I removed the scipy dependency and used others.